# Confused how to work with .map or .reduce or foreach

Tags: javascript, arrays, object

I am new to JavaScript. I am little confused even after reading multiple answers and Mozilla.org docs... My issue is that if there's a simple array I am able to use .map,.filter easily but if array has objects then it becomes a little confusing.

E.g. - I have to add all ages here.

I know .map might not work as it gives a new array (which I don't want here), .filter won't work (that's for returning elements that satisfy given condition), forEach don't returns anything.

I am not allowed to use for loop but that's the most convenient here (Below code is correct & working).

How else can I solve it?

```js
const users=[
  {firstName:"john",lastName:"Biden",age:26},
  {firstName:"jimmy",lastName:"cob",age:75},
  {firstName:"sam",lastName:"lewis",age:50},
  {firstName:"Ronald",lastName:"Mathew",age:26},  
];
var total=0
//console.log(users.length)
for(let i=0;i<users.length;i++){
    //console.log(users[i].age)
   total+=users[i].age
}

console.log(total)
```

Comment: You probably want to use [array.reduce](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/reduce). If you want to divide the task into smaller steps, you could first use `map` to extract the age of each user object, then `reduce` to add the ages together.

Comment: So what is your goal? What do you want to accomplish?

Comment: @ScottMarcus `I have to add all ages here without using a for loop`

Comment: Then `.forEach()` is the way to go, since it doesn't mutate the array and doesn't create a new one.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use forEach where you use the for

You can use map to make an array of ages and reduce it to sum it

You can use filter to count only those above or equal to 50 years of age

The `({age})` is using destructuring to get a just the age of the object array as an alternative to `total=users.map(item => { return item.age })`

```js
const users=[
  {firstName:"john",lastName:"Biden",age:26},
  {firstName:"jimmy",lastName:"cob",age:75},
  {firstName:"sam",lastName:"lewis",age:50},
  {firstName:"Ronald",lastName:"Mathew",age:26},  
];

// forEach needs the total initialised

let total=0
users.forEach(user => total+=user.age)
console.log(total)

// map plus reduce (to sum) does not need to initialise

total=users.map(({age}) => age)
.reduce((a,b) => a+b)
console.log(total)

// filter plus reduce also does not need initialising the total

let total50Plus=users.filter(({age}) => age>=50)
.reduce((a,b) => a.age+b.age)   // does not need an accumulator initialised
console.log(total50Plus)

// the standard reduce initialises the accumulator at the end of the function

total=users.reduce((acc,{age}) => acc+=age,0);  
console.log(total)

// full version 

total=users.reduce((accumulator, current) => {
  accumulator += current.age;
  return accumulator;
},0); // initialise the accumulator 
console.log(total)
```

Comment: Hi sir, Can you please explain this line ```total=users.map(({age}) => age)```, haven't seen this, I am learning on ES6. thanks --> i mean the curly and normal brackets of age after .map

Comment: "me too" - I'm curious, why use `({age}) => age` instead of `(u) => u.age`?

Comment: It is called destructuring. I could do `total=users.map(item => { return item.age })` but the destructuring is (mostly) shorter when using more than one letter for the item ;)

Comment: Thanks mplungjan — I do tend to use single-letters and the `return` is not necessary so I end up with `users.map((u) => u.age)` which I find more readable ... but maybe that's because I don't use destructuring often enough to be used to your notation.

Answer (score 0):

Using ForEach it will be practical to manipulate your array of objects.
Understand the parameters used in the forEach callback:

> **currentValue (user)**
>
> The current value of the element being processed in the array.

> **optional index**
>
> The index of the current element being processed in the array.

> **optional array**
>
> The array that forEach() is being applied to.

In the example below follows the code of what you want using forEach.

```
const users = [
  {firstName:"john",lastName:"Biden",age:26},
  {firstName:"jimmy",lastName:"cob",age:75},
  {firstName:"sam",lastName:"lewis",age:50},
  {firstName:"Ronald",lastName:"Mathew",age:26},  
];

let total = 0;

users.forEach(function(user, index, array) {
    total += user.age;
});

console.log(total);
```

Comment: yes but my confusion was when it doesn't return anything then how and why to use it? And .map .reduce seemed better fit for this role. Thanks for answering